# Change MS Project 2010 task text color by flag field

Tags: highlighting, microsoft-project-2010

I want to change the text color (at least) for tasks that deliver a document. I setup the custom field "Flag 18" to show whether this line item is a document or not. I can change the gantt bar color based on a flag field but how do I change the text formatting for that line item based on the flag?

Comment: I have found a way by creating a filter based on the flag and calling it "Documents". It then shows up in the highlight pull down. I can then highlight all of the documents in the plan. But it will only highlight one (1) filter or flag at a time with only the one color. How can I highlight, change text format, for multiple flags or filters wth corresponding multiple colors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no automated way to change the text color of flagged tasks.  You can, as you noted, change the bar color.  You can use the **Marked** field and set a specific text style for marked tasks, but again, only one color per marked field.